# How to install Composer on a Mac?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to get the Laravel PHP framework installed and for that I need to install Composer. However I'm getting stuck there. I installed it before for Symfony but I couldn't get it to work so I think I deleted it.

When I open the terminal on Mac and enter one of the commands for installing composer like:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

I get:

```
-bash: php: command not found
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1635)
```

Why is this?

Comment: I installed php but I still get the same message

Comment: Try `locate bin/php | less` to see a scrollable list of possible locations for your PHP binary (it may be a long list). The correct one will just be named "php". Macs have PHP installed by default, so it is odd that it cannot find it.

Comment: I think I deleted some files, I did a repair install of os x and it works fine now. Thanks for the help both of you :)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can install it via Brew.

First, install [Brew](https://brew.sh/);

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Then you can use Brew to install Composer;

```
brew install composer
```

That's it, it's now installed. You can verify this by running `composer --version`

Comment: Most Mac developers will have Homebrew already installed. So this is the easiest approach.

Answer (score 20):

1. download file from https://getcomposer.org/installer
2. execute the file

```
sudo php installer
```

3. and move the file

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: How can I execute the file? I just download the file and open it. I found some codes in that

Comment: for example ..keep it is download directory. and using CLI got to that path. list all elements there using "ls" command (git bash). u will see installer file. run "sudo php installer" now and mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer later. hope this helps.

Answer (score 14):

Here it is:

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: Worked on MacOS Sierra

Answer (score 10):

First install brew if not installed in Mac:

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Update brew and install php and composer.

```
$ brew update
$ brew install php
$ brew install composer
```

Verify by checking version:

```
 $ composer -V
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
~ which php
/usr/bin/php

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | /usr/bin/php
```

Answer (score 1):

just open your terminal and follow this steps,
here odbase is username of my mac.

```
cd /Users/odbase/Downloads

php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"

php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '93b54496392c062774670ac18b134c3b3a95e5a5e5c8f1a9f115f203b75bf9a129d5daa8ba6a13e2cc8a1da0806388a8') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"

php composer-setup.php

php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

php composer.phar

mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

(if this produce error please run with prefix sudo. {sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer})

installed for check

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ls
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted some files that I should not have deleted. Did a repair install of OS X and now it works.